# How to save TCP server config in esp8266, so that it is retained on reboot?

Tags: tcp, server, esp8266

- I am newest in esp8266.
- I could configure esp8266 as a tcp server, but after it is turned off and then turn on, esp8266's tcp sever gets disabled!
  Please help me!
  In fact for this I passed this Level:

  AT+CIPMUX=1

then

```
AT+CIPSERVER=1,8888
```

That works as well as when esp8266 is turn on but when I disconnect power and then turn on settings are lost and when I use

```
AT+CIPMUX?
```

that returns

```
CIPMUX:0
```

Please help me!

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking for. Can you clarify what steps you have taken, and what the outputs were?

Comment: I think it is a legit question; I ran into this myself with a smart relay I got at Amazon that needed these commands sent on every reset, which made the device basically unusable. It took me a couple of days to research and experiment until I learned that this is just how the stock firmware on these devices is, and that you can easily create your own with Arduino, which will start in the mode you need and do what you need. A good answer to this question would actually help me at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a power reset or restart,  CMUX and CIPSERVER must be applied again. You can use the following reset procedure:

```
// close active connection
AT+CIPCLOSE=id
// stop server
AT+CIPSERVER=0
// restart
AT+RST
// enable multiple connections (required for server mode)
AT+CIPMUX=1
// start listening
AT+CIPSERVER=1,8888
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@nowir3s/getting-started-with-esp8266-875fb54441d6

Comment: thanks very much!but I have new problem!for run ino file in esp8266 I installed Arduino 1.6.5 and then install esp boards and then copy esp8266com to hardware folder!but I cant see esptool in programmer menu!I use windows7 32bit!please help me!

Comment: esptool does not need to be selected as a programmer. You can just hit upload. Check the conversation [here](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/esp8266-Arduino/issues/2)

Comment: Glad to help. Good that it helped